# How can I dynamically update dropdown lists in a Flutter Bloc when selecting a new country or state in a country state city picker?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I want to do country state city picker with dropdownformfields.I got some progress but i stuck some situation.Problem is when user selects dropdowns and after user decided change country or state my dropdown got error.And i think this problem because of when list selected datas filled but after change country or state list is not changing.I drop my gist link u guys inspect easily.

https://gist.github.com/melihcelik09/43b3d6e9f6c997361428b6e05bbb90c2

My first method is when user select country i set empty city and state list before the fetching operaiton but still i got same error.